# if springboot can start from just one class, and inject just its depenecies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Sometime when i just debug some bugs in one interface(maybe a few related classes exist,a @Controller class and several @Service classes),

```
@RestController
public class A  {

    @Autowired
    private B b;
    @Autowired
    private C c;
}

@Service
class B{
}

@Service
class C{
}
```

i need to start the springboot application. but when the project classes increase. it's too slow. i know i can use devtool such as jrebel to hot deploy. i just wanna know if there have any methods for user to start application but using one specific class. In this scenario, i mean the class A

Comment: `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: That is why you should write unit tests. Just write a test that instantiates Class A and mocks B and C so you can check if it behaves properly. Do the same for the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can tackle this:

1. unit tests. Write a test for class A where you mock B and C to test what you want.
2. if you want web tier test, you can use `@SpringBootTest`, with this you can also mock B and C, and run api calls to A and test it. there are nice examples for that [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Comment: If you only want web tier tests use `@WebMvcTest` not `@SpringBootTest`. The first is dedicated for web testing and will only start that, the `@SpringBootTest` will bootstrap your whole context.

Comment: the example above I list is a simple depenecies graph, actually it has some much depenecies. And mock each depenecy  is not realistic. What i want is when start the application, i can specify a web tier class(via env or argument).  only this class's mapping is active and its depenecies are  init, other web tier class are inactive and their depenecies are not init